# How to make object hidden to start its animation?

Tags: jquery, css, delay

I wrote an animation and then I implemented and delayed it into my html code via jquery. But then i realized that animation doesn't go smoothly (it's from the very biginning then dissapears and then comes to the screen corectly). I want to make this object hidden for 1,25s and then start with the animation at the same time. I have some trouble with displaying my code on this site (stack overflow), sorry for that.

**JS:**

```
<script>
setTimeout( function(){
$('#myobject').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
}, 1250)
</script>
```

**CSS:**
`

```
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355,1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    }

    0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
    }

    60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(25px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(25px, 0, 0);
    }

    75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    }

    90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
    }

    to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    }
    }
    @keyframes bounceInLeft {
    from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    }

    0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
    }

    60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(25px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(25px, 0, 0);
    }

    75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    }

    90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
    }

    to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    }
    }

    .bounceInLeft {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

you should add `opacity:0;` to your object

this way it will not show untill the animation starts

```
#myobject{
   opacity:0;
}
```

Add another class with `opacity:1;` and make it important:

```
.visible{

  opacity:1!important;
}
```

and add it in your script with the other classes

```
setTimeout( function(){
$('#myobject').addClass('animated bounceInLeft visible');
}, 1250)
```

This will make it stay visible after the end of the animation.

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/oocLvfrg/)

Comment: But then it dissapears also after animation. I want it to stay on the screen.

Comment: I resolved the problem you just need to add another class with opacity:1 see my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I really appreciate your help. But I just added this "opacity: 1!important;" to ".bounceInLeft".

Comment: for me i prefer to create a new class just in case if i use it in another place...i don't want to change the classes everytime :)